# How can I pass PHP variable to Datepicker in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datepicker

I'm trying to set the default date in datepicker with a variable I pass into the html from PHP.  Here's a simplified version of both my control file and form:

control file:

```
<?php
  function render($template, $values = []) {        
      // extract variables into local scope
         extract($values);           

      // render template
         require("$template");
}

  $default_date = date("m/d/Y") ;       
  $default_date = strtotime($default_date);
  $default_date = $default_date + 604800;
  $default_date = date("Y,m-1,d",$default_date);
  render("index_month2_form.php",['default_date'=> $default_date]);
?>
```

and here is the form:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <?php print "$default_date"; ?> 
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jqueryui/css/swanky-purse/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css">
  <script src="/jqueryui/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"> </script>
  <script src="jqueryui/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>  
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() { 
       $("#mydate").datepicker ({
          onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
                 var dateAsString = dateText;     
                 var date = $('#mydate').val();       
          }
       }) 
       //.datepicker("setDate",new Date());  
       .datepicker("setDate",new Date(2014,10-1,17));  
      });  
  </script>   
 </head>
 <body> 
  <p>Date: <input type="text" id="mydate"></p> 
 </body>
</html>
```

If I use the commented line for setDate I get the current date.  If I use the line I have I get the date 7 days forward.  When I print $default_date at the top of the form I get 2014,10-1,17  but I can't firgure out of way to pass this into the script.  Others have suggested using

Comment: others have suggested using <?php echo but that doesn't work inside the script.

Comment: There was was an extra right bracket ")" in the PHP code in the HTML form. I fixed that for you.

Comment: thanks but could you tell me the exact line the extra ")" was on?  I can't find it in my code??

Comment: Never mind, it's my bad. There is no extra ")". Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using echo is the way to go.
I would rather put it in the script rather than the input
I assume `$default_date === "2014,10-1,17"`

```
$(function() { 
       $("#mydate").datepicker ({
          onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
                 var dateAsString = dateText;     
                 var date = $('#mydate').val();       
          }
       }) 
       //.datepicker("setDate",new Date());  
       .datepicker("setDate",new Date(
<?php
     $date = explode(',', $default_date);
     echo $date[0] .  ',' . $date[1] . ',' . $date[2]; 
?>
     ));  
};
```

edit:
As rss81 noticed it, destructuring the string to rebuild the exact same string is quite dumb. I dont know what I was thinking...
Nevertheless I'll let it like this for educational purpose.

exploding the string enables us to get an array of the string of each chunk separated by a coma. You could use it to reorder the string. For instance if you wanted to transform "2014,10-1,17" to "10-1,2014,17" that would be done by `echo $date[1].','.$date[0].','.$date[2]`

*Echo* enables us to output the html page as we like, making it dynamic. So here we are preprocessing the date argument of the *.datepicker()* by php.

Comment: @rss81 i will add explanation when I get time so you can understand whats going on ;)

Comment: I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi,  since $default_date is already in the right format I found that the following works too:  <?php echo $default_date ?>

Comment: @rss81 correct ! You understand the code I see, welldone :) I updated the answer as promised

Answer (score 1):

The better solution is to assign returned PHP date variable to jQuery variable.

This can be done by following

```
var phpDate = "<?php echo $default_date; ?>";
```

Now, you need to assign that to datepicker

```
$("#mydate").datepicker("setDate",phpDate);
```

This works...

Comment: where do you place the var phpdate line?

Comment: in the setDate line phpdate has to be a date object so this doesn't work. the solution below by Guillaume works but all the other responses do not.  Really appreciate everyone's help

Comment: this almost works and is elegant. place `var phpDate` before `$("#mydate").datepicker{` and change it to `var phpDate = new Date("<?php echo $default_date;?>");`

Comment: or change `$('#mydate')[...]` to `$('#mydate').datepicker('setDate', new Date(phpDate));` depending on what you like better

Comment: You need to place it with in the <script> tag in head section or at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Just give the input the relative value

```
<input type="text" id="mydate" value="<?php echo $yourdate; ?>">
```

This will init datepicker with you date value

Hope this helped and my apologies if this is not what you were looking for

Comment: I've tried this and it just defaults to the current date.  It does not work but thanks for trying

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<?php echo` not in the script, but in the body, in some display:none element with id. And then just to get the date with javascript from that element and set to datapicker

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the $default_date value in a data attribute of an html element. For example:

```
<p id="myDate" data-date="<?php echo $default_date; ?>"></p>
```

After that you can extract it with with Jquery like this:

```
var date = $("#myDate").data("date");
```

Comment: i tried this but it just doesn't work.this is so frustrating.  where do you place the var line?  what format should the date be in?

Comment: Well, I don't know about the specific format accepted by the datepicker, but you can define the variable date in the anonymous javascript function where you call the datepicker. I supposed that the $default_date variable was already in the right format.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set date format in javascript part because it's create and problem with date.

You can set it given below

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "yy-mm-dd ");
```